# JavaScript: Automatically Redirect a Page with Post Parameters

Tags: javascript, redirect, post, parameters

I have a page like below:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>

  <form name="myform" action="http://www.example.com/page" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="param1" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="param2" value="2">
    <input type="hidden" name="param3" value="3">
    <input type="submit" value="Click Here If Not Redirect">
  </form>

  <script language="JavaScript">
    document.myform.submit();
  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

I want a JavaScript code (No jQuery or something, the lightweight is very important in my project) to do the things above (Automatically redirect a page with POST parameters). I don't want the user to see the redirect page. For example something like this:

```
<html>
   <head>
      <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://www.example.com/page">
      <meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache">
      <meta http-equiv="expires" content="-1">
   </head>
   <body>
   </body>
</html>
```

But of course with POST parameters.

Is there any solution to my problem?

Comment: if i understood your problem correctly then you can use window.redirect and pass parameters as query string

Comment: Thank you for the comment. Is there any way to POST the parameters? My first codes above is POSTing parameters but the user see the page about 5 to 10 seconds. In the second code, I can't POST the parameters but the user redirects as soon as he/she see the page (less than a second). Thank you in Advance.

Answer (score 2):

Send the form with ajax

```html
    <html>

    <head></head>

    <body>

      <form name="myform" id="myFormElement" action="http://www.example.com/page" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="param1" value="1">
        <input type="hidden" name="param2" value="2">
        <input type="hidden" name="param3" value="3">
        <input type="submit" onclick="submitAjax()">
      </form>

      <script language="JavaScript">
        var form = document.getElementById("myFormElement");
        function submitAjax() {
          var data = new FormData(form);

          var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
          xhr.open('POST', 'http://www.stackoverflow.com', true);
          xhr.onload = function() {
            // got a response for the post now redirect the user to 
            // "my portal... so I can do things in my portal... 
            // in the router's little web server."
            window.location.href = "http://wherever.com/you/want/to/go/now";
            console.log(this.responseText);
          };
          xhr.send(data);

        }
        form.onsubmit = function(e){
          e.preventDefault();
          submitAjax();
        }

      </script>

    </body>

    </html>
```

Comment: I've said that, I don't want the user to see the page. In this way he/she has to submit the form him/herself.

Comment: They won't see any other page, the user will stay on the same page when they submit, and it's up to you what to do when you get the response

Comment: The page is on the router and I can't do my stuff in there. I have to redirect the user to my portal (with parameters from the router), so I can do things in my portal. And this page will be copy in the router's little web server.